# Blender 2.8 How do i make objects with Render View disabled to not be visible on Viewport / OpenGL Rendering?

Tags: 3d-view, opengl, viewlayers

I have some objects which i do not want to be disible on the Viewport nor the OpenGL rendering previews, back in 2.79 it worked just fine by disabling render view on the outliner and enabling the 'only render' box on the right side pannel (the one you view with N on 2.79)
and now in 2.8 there's the 'hide overlays' option but it doesn't hide those objects anymore.

is there a way to get the same result in 2.8??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just written an addon for that:
https://github.com/artellblender/show_only_render

It does not update automatically though, so it's necessary to click again the box to hide/unhide newly hidden objects

Comment: omg i know im extremely late but thank you a million! this is gonna make viewport rendering more pleasant to preview, *hugs really tight* >U<

Answer (score 2):

The options are still there, they are just hidden in the filter dropdown:
[image]

Make sure all the buttons are selected. I think they did this to keep the UI cleaner, but I'd probably have left on at least render visibility option by default. Hey, it's still a Beta though, so maybe they will "fix" that. :)

Comment: it kinda is what i was looking for but the goal i had in mind was to be able to still see the object in viewport but for it to not be renderable in opengl, so like the object is shown but at the moment i hit opengl render it hides automatically, just like the render view one except its for opengl render

Comment: The camera icon will hide it in the render. You need to enable those buttons in the filter as shown above for them to be visible in the outliner. If your object is still showing up in the render with the camera button dissabled, it's a bug, though it's not one I'm currently seeing.

Comment: Also, feel free to upvote my answer if it helped. :)

Comment: I think it would be better if this was a viewport option; as it stand, I need to keyframe both render and viewport visibility for all objects to preview animations in the viewport.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately it seems there's no more "Only Render" option to show only the renderable objects in the Blender 2.8 viewport. Only "overlays" object can be hidden (lights, cameras, bones...).

Comment: Not true. See my answer above, and upvote it if it helped. All options are there, they just are not turned on by default. Turn them on easily in the filter options.

Comment: I fail to see how your answer relates to the question: how to hide all non-renderable objects in a similar way to the "Only Render" feature of Blender 2.79.
Yes we can enable or disable objects from rendering/viewport one by one in the outliner, but it's not convenient.

Comment: You can hide any object or groups of objects from the render by first placing those objects in a collection, then disabling whichever things you don't want on the collection. Blender 2.80 uses collections for this purpose, and yes, objects can belong to multiple collections.

Comment: I understand that. But this is a manual workflow, while it's automated in Blender 2.79: one click only.

Comment: @C.Rogers the goal is not to have everything in a group or in one collection to disable rendering in that group or collection, but a button to quickly preview render and show only renderable objects. How 2.8 viewport works now is not convenient to some particular tasks. This is still not possible with 2.8 as far as i know and this is an essential function to many people.

Comment: It's not a "goal". Collections can be used in a variety of useful ways, and as I said before, objects can be in multiple collections at once. It's really not my problem if people don't want to use them. They are a fantastic multitool and I much prefer them to layers or special purpose buttons to hide things. To each their own. The OP found my answer to be at least a decent work around, so I'm satisfied I've helped with my answer. No one seems to have anything better at this point.

Comment: As far as I can tell, Collection visibility in viewport and renders cannot be keyframed. That would have been a nice feature.

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar got ya, where you can enable and disable the rendering in real time and and at render time respectively. The setting is in the particle panel, next to the drawing pin and the +-, small monitor and camera.

Cheers