# is there a way to enable disable collections with driver or script?

Tags: scripting, drivers, collections

Is there any script that does this? i cant place drivers on a collection so i thought a script would do the job... not necessarily a driver adding one but something i can control with a property value of an object.

- Example: lets say i have a cube, and this cube has a property in it, so when that property value is 1 it hides the collection the cube is inside it

i had a similar problem which was solved [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/158317/68753) using [this script](https://github.com/artellblender/show_only_render) as an addon